# How to monitor endpoint?

Tags: http, botframework

I'm trying to monitor the endpoint of my bot built with the Microsoft Bot Framework.
To do so, I'm using the WorldPing plugin from Grafana: https://grafana.com/plugins/raintank-worldping-app

The problem is, this endpoint return an error 405 when I do a GET request, which is perfectly normal, but WorldPing then think that my endpoint is unavailable.

Do you know any workaround or solution to monitor the endpoint?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: You can authorize this request on your bot side

Comment: Hmmm yeah, I guess I could but I'm not sure it's a good idea in term of security...

Comment: Not sure what you want here. You will get the error when you make a `GET` request to a `POST` endpoint, so why not a) make a `POST` request or b) add a `GET` endpoint?

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you.

Comment: @Pierrick that's what I said for the "b" version. You will try what, "a" ?

Comment: @NicolasR oh ok, I didn't understand that sorry. I think I'll go with the "b" version.